# Restricting Age without using TRIGGER constraint MySQL

Tags: mysql, constraints, mysql-5.6

Requirement: A doctor should have age over 24

Env: MySQL 5.6

Someone says: "You do not need Trigger for this. Solution is very simple"

Options tried: CHECK does not work with this version of MySQL. Also I cannot use fuctions like Curdate() for CHECK constraints. I ended up using trigger and it works. but I want to know what is that SIMPLE SOLUTION is

What I have now is a Trigger:

```
BEGIN
IF NEW.DateofBirth > date_add(CURDATE(),interval -24 year)     
       then SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Should be over 24 years old';
    END IF;
END
```

So far I have used DateOfBirth becuase Age column does not make sense in real life.
I am lost after googling for Generated column, ENUM, etc.

Comment: You haven't told us how you are populating the db so hard to say.  You could use a procedure to insert data wherein you could test age but a trigger is a better mysql option. If you are front ending mysql then you could test there.

Comment: BTW that's really ageist - don't qualifications count?

Comment: Since MySQL 8.0 you can use constraint check can be used. For MySQL 5.* only trigger is possible solution